# How to create endpoint url in salesforce org to use in rest resource

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, apexrest

Rest Api. I wanna to create a link to be able to get api calls

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/GetByDate/*')
global class RetutnLeadsByDateRestResource {
    @HttpPost
    global static void getLeadsbyDate(){
        String startDate =  RestContext.request.params.get('start');
        String endDate =  RestContext.request.params.get('end');
        List<lead> ls = database.query('select id,name,email from lead where createddate > ' + startDate+'T00:00:00Z');
        ls = [select id,name from lead limit 10];
        system.debug(RestContext.request);
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('response is:'+Json.serialize(ls));
    }
}
```

Tested on workbench and now i need to create endpoint. When i use

> https://myorg.my.salesforce.com/GetByDate/

I'm getting error:
[
{
"message": "Session expired or invalid",
"errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
}
]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you read the basic documentation on this topic, as it covers your question. Specifically, [Apex REST Basic Code Sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) shows a CURL example:

> ```
> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId" "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/accountId"
> ```

Note that you need to set an `Authorization` header, and the url format is `/services/apexrest/MyMapping`.

Answer (score -3):

Go to setup -> sites and find active url. That is url i can use